# How to clear database before seeding in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite, sqlite3-ruby

Is there a simple line of code I can include at the top of my seed file to clear out each table before inserting new seed data without running any rake commands to rollback tables or databases?

I was thinking something like:

```
[Foo, Bar].each{|class| class.destroy_all}
```

The point is I want to add new data where each new insertion starts from id: 1. What I want to avoid is deleting a table with 100 rows and when I add new data it's starting from 101.

Comment: which DB you're using ?

Comment: I'm using SQLite locally and PostgreSQL through Heroku. This is my first SO question... how do I mark it answered? Also, after doing some more research, I found the database_cleaner gem whereby I just added `DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)` at the top of my seed file and Bingo! :) Thanks for the help Vishal!

Comment: [How to mark question as answered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Updated Answer**
You've to install *(OR you can add `gem 'database_cleaner'` to your Gemfile)* a GEM called [Database Cleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) which helps to clean your database without affecting your database schema._
To clean your database each time whenever you do `rake db:seed` then paste

```
# updated
require 'database_cleaner'

DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
```

on the top of your seed file. ***It'll clear your database and start count from `1` again.***
***Disclaimer :** This updated answer is tested, and working perfectly in my system.*

**===========================================================================**

**Previous Untested Answer**

Ya you can do that but it's depends on which database you're using.

Below I'm giving solution for some popular DBs.

In **MySQL**, `TRUNCATE table;` *deletes all rows and resets the auto increment counter*.

In **PostgreSQL**, *it does not do this automatically.* You can use `TRUNCATE TABLE table RESTART IDENTITY;`.

In **SQLite**, *there is no **TRUNCATE** statement*, instead, it's

```
DELETE FROM table;
DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name='table';
```

**You can also try this**

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table|
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE #{table}")
end
```

You can select any one of the solution & implement it to your seed file.

*I hope this will help you... ;)*

*Disclaimer : I've share my knowledge for the purpose of your help, but this solution was didn't tested.*

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables` could delete your migrations table...

Answer (score 3):

You can use this command

```
rake db:reset
```

Answer (score 2):

In my Rails 5 environment.

```
rails db:purge
rails db:migrate
rails db:seed
```

Or all together.

```
rails db:purge db:migrate db:seed
```

Comment: Nice. Don't forget you can chain these like `rails db:foo db:bar`

Answer (score 1):

As of Rails 6, you can run

```
rails db:seed:replant
```

which will truncate the database before seeding.

Answer (score 0):

Before doing the `rake db:seed`.

```
rake db:purge
```

has recently been added to ActiveRecord in the master branch of rails 4.2.0.alpha

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/e2f232aba15937a4b9d14bd91e0392c6d55be58d

Comment: Not sure if this resets the counts for new ids, but this is how to do it for sqlite3: `sql = "delete from sqlite_sequence where name = '#{table}'";ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)`

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more research on this topic, I found the 'database_cleaner' gem. After installing, I simply added `DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)` at the top of my seed.rb and Bingo! It seems to have worked locally running SQLite and with PostgreSQL on Heroku. Thanks for all the input everyone! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Without removing(dropping) database:**

rollback all migrations, for example if they < 1000 and after migrate and seed

```
STEP=1000 rails db:rollback && rails db:migrate && rails db:seed
```

or

```
rails db:purge && rails db:migrate && rails db:seed
```

**With removing(dropping) database:**

remove(drop) database + create database + migrate + seed

```
rails db:reset
```

or

```
rails db:drop && rails db:create && rails db:migrate && rails db:seed
```